# Can I get on-premises gateway, API invocation statistics to my WSO2 API cloud account?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, ibm-api-management, hybrid-cloud

I have an on-premises gateway running locally which is connected to my WSO2 API Cloud account and I have created an API in this Cloud account.
I haven't invoked this API from the API Cloud console. I have only invoked it from the on-premises gateway.
When I check the statistics for this API in the cloud, it shows that I haven't invoked this API.
But I was under the impression that the on-premises gateway statistics can be viewed from cloud.
Am I missing any sort of configuration or is this the expected behavior?

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your on-premise gateway to publish statistics to APIM analytics server in the cloud.

You will have to change the API-M_HOME/repository/conf/api-manager.xml file's analytics url and credentials to cloud analytics server.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Configuring+APIM+Analytics#StandardSetup